# Adding a user during startup of a machine using CloudFormation

Tags: authentication, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a user using CloudFormation after startup of a Linux machine.
I use the following code to do so:

```
  Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    config:
      groups:
        ansible: {}
      users:
        ansible:
          groups:
            - "ansible"
          homeDir: "/home/ansible"
      files:
        /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys:
          content: !Sub |
            '{{ resolve:secretsmanager:
              arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:account:secret:secretname:
                SecretString:
                  secretstringpath }}'
          mode: "000644"
          owner: "ansible"
          group: "ansible"
Properties:
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      yum update -y
      yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v \
        --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
        --resource LinuxEC2Instance \
        --region ${AWS::Region}
```

However, during startup I get the following error message:

> [   96.72999017] cloud-init[2959]: Error occurred during build: Failed to add user ansible

What does this error mean? It does not seem to work as expected the way I do it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can assign users to custom groups, you have to create such groups.

For that there is [groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-groups) option in `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`.

For example:

```
groups: 
  ansible: {}
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked, however, now I have this error right after:
Error occurred during build: Failed to add user ansible.

Any idea what I have to do here? Its the same code except that I added groups: ansible {} as suggested

Comment: No problem. Not sure you can use `uid: 1`. May leave it out and see.

Comment: It did not solve the issue, the error remains the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Benny Can you update the question with new state of your template? I can try to replicate the issue.

Comment: I updated the codebase, if you could try it and let me know that would be great! ;)

Comment: @Benny WIll try. Btw, what disto is that? Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: Yes, it is Amazon Linux 2, just a question regarding this, if I want to for example make this work with other distros lets say RHEL7 instead of AL2 would that approach work there, too and for most other Linux distros?

Comment: Ok great,thanks! Let me know if it works for you and what you did please! ;)

Comment: @Benny I have the same error :-( The workaround is to just use `UserData`: `adduser ansible -g ansible`. Don't know what can be causing it. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! It worked adding the users using userdata! I have one last issue to solve, I need to copy the certificate content into the .ssh folder, I tried using it this way '{{ resolve:secretsmanager:
              arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:account:secret:secretname:
                SecretString:
                  secretstringpath }}'

But this does not resolve the content from the secretsmanager, it simply saves this whole string as content into the file, any idea how to do this correctly? Thanks so much, you really help me out here!

Comment: @Benny Cool. Glad to hear. Maybe you can create new question with the relevant info. For now I have to finish. This way someone else might be able to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across the `Error occurred during build: Failed to add user` error mentioned by Benny above, I managed to solve this by creating a second config and creating the users within it:

```
  Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
  configSets: 
    ascending: 
      - "config1"
      - "config2"
    descending: 
      - "config2"
      - "config1"
    config1:
      groups:
        ansible: {}
    config2:
      users:
        ansible:
          groups:
            - "ansible"
          homeDir: "/home/ansible"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by adding the custom group with the same name as the new user. When CFN Init creates a new user it automatically creates a new group with the same name. So adding the custom group with the same name as the user is unnecessary and causes it throw this error when it tries to create the group again:

```
2023-03-02 14:18:55,764 [INFO] Created group nwuser successfully
2023-03-02 14:19:15,893 [ERROR] Failed to add user nwuser
2023-03-02 14:19:15,894 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of inst: Failed to add user nwuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/posix_security.py", line 77, in create_or_modify_user
    user_record = pwd.getpwnam(user_name)
KeyError: "getpwnam(): name not found: 'nwuser'"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 255, in build
    changes['users'] = UserTool().apply(self._config.users)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/user_group_tools.py", line 83, in apply
    if security.create_or_modify_user(name, attributes.get("groups", []), attributes.get("homeDir", None), uid):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/posix_security.py", line 82, in create_or_modify_user
    _create_user(user_name, groups, homedir, uid)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/posix_security.py", line 147, in _create_user
    raise ToolError("Failed to add user %s" % user_name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Failed to add user nwuser
```